# react-router-dom Link not working without refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using `reactjs` as functional compontent and want to link another compontent to current one, after I update `react-router-dom` to new version `6.2.1` this problem occured:

Login.js

```
<Button color={'secondary'}>
<Link className={'text-light'} to={'/register'}>
Register
</Link>
</Button>
```

I reload this page, and then click on this button, it's work, and will goes to `/register` but when n I use browser <kbd>Back</kbd> button, back to `/login` and then click again on button to go to `/register` again, but this time not working, until I reload page again. any idea?

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
```

Here is App.js

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Router/>
</React.Fragment>
```

Router.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
const CommonRoute = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Index/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
};
export default CommonRoute;
```

After click on link browser give me an warning:

> You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your
> component is first rendered.

Comment: By any chance is your `Button` component overriding the onClick of the Link? Also you don't need `exact` anymore for your `Route`

Comment: @RichardHpa I used `<Link className={'text-light'} to={'/register'}>Register</Link>` without button, still not working

Comment: unable to reproduce - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dtsyer?file=index.tsx)